# Can not make SerializerMethodField() work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have this view, I passed the request through the context to the serializer so I can use it to get the user

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Handle member creation from invitation code. """
        serializer = AddMemberSerializer(
            data=request.data,
            context={'circle': self.circle, 'request': request} 
        ) 
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        member = serializer.save()

        data = self.get_serializer(member).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In the serializer I did this but it does not work,I get "KeyError: 'user'", I ran a debugger and when I tried to call the get_user method it says "TypeError: get_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'"

```
user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_user(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request:
            return request.user
```

So what am I missing? I looked up other implementations of this field and none of them seem very different of mine, so I would really apreciate it if someone explains to me why it is not working.

Also if there is a more efective way to get the user into a field (Need it to run a user_validate method on it)

Comment: `SerializerMethodField()` is read-only, you can't use it for creating.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return obj.user_id
```